# Git - Push a directory and then ignore it

Tags: git, phpstorm, push

I have a folder containing all my http requests files that I execute on PhpStorm. 
I added first this folder to my gitignore file :

```
/app/http/
```

Then I forced to push it to my remote repository:

```
git add -f app/http
git commit -m 'http folder added'
git push
```

But after that, my folder is not ignored.
How can I ignore it after pushed it ?

Comment: If you have already pushed it to remote repo then you have to remove that file first alongside correcting your gitignore configuration.

Comment: But I want to keep my directory on my remote repo. But after my first add, i want to ignore it. If I remove it, it will be removed on remote side too after pushed it. Sorry, i'm beginner on git.

Comment: Hımm, I don't know the answer but curios about it. Lets wait someone who is capable of git operations such this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## TL;DR

You can't get what you want.  Don't do it that way.  Consider instead storing one dot-file, such as a `.gitignore` that lists `*`, if that's OK.  If not, consider having a *program that is not Git* create the empty folder automatically when needed.

## Long

There are a number of incorrect assumptions that you have started with:

- You think you added a folder, but a Git commit only stores *files*, not folders.  We'll see what that means, and why Git is like this, in a moment.
- You think you pushed the folder and/or the files.  Git does not push files.  Git pushes *commits*.
- You think that listing something in `.gitignore` makes Git ignore it.  That is not the case.

These all led to the problem you've encountered.

You need to start with this: Git's basic unit of storage—the one you'll interact with, anyway—is the *commit*.  Git is all about *commits*, so you need to know, in some detail, exactly what a commit is and does.

#### Commits

A Git commit is made up of two parts: data, and metadata:

- The data in each commit consist of a complete snapshot of files.  There are no folders here, there are just files whose names may contain embedded slashes, such as `path/to/file.ext`.
- The metadata in each commit contain things like your name and email address, the date-and-time stamp of when you made the commit, and your log message explaining *why* you made the commit.  Included with this metadata—which is meant for *you* to use, rather than for Git—is some metadata that really *is* for Git: a list of *parent commit hash IDs*.  Usually there is just one commit hash ID in this list.

Each commit has a unique hash ID.  This hash ID is, in effect, the true name of the commit.  It's how Git retrieves the data—your files—and metadata.  So you need to use commit hashes, so that Git can *find* the commits.  But there is a problem here: commit hash IDs are big and ugly and impossible for humans to work with.

#### Branch names

The solution to this problem is obvious: we have a *computer;* we can have the computer store the hash IDs for us, using a simple name, such as `master` or `develop`, that humans can handle, to remember the right hash ID.  This is what branch names are: a branch name holds the hash ID of one—and *only* one—commit.  The commit we have Git remember in a branch name is the *newest* or *latest* commit in the branch, by definition.  Git calls this the *tip commit*.

If we say `git checkout master`, Git will check out the tip commit of `master` by using the hash ID stored in the name `master`.  If we add a *new* commit *to* the branch, Git will write out the new commit, with its (single) *parent* hash ID set to the old branch tip.  The new commit gets a new, unique hash ID, which Git writes into the branch name, and now the *new* commit is the branch tip.

The previous commit still exists, and Git can find it on its own: Git uses the branch name to find the hash ID of the *last* commit, then reads that commit and uses its metadata to find the hash ID of the parent.  Git then uses that hash ID to read the parent commit.  If appropriate, Git uses *that* commit's stored parent to go back one more step.

#### Draw your commits and branches

Visually, if we draw this, we get:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <--branch
```

where `branch` is the branch name, which stores some hash ID that we'll just call `H` here.  That allows Git to *find* `H`.  `H` itself stores, as its parent hash ID, the ID of a commit we'll just call `G`.  So `H` *points to* `G`, allowing Git to retrieve `G` from its database.  `G` in turn points to earlier commit `F`, and so on.  The whole process works because the *branch name* points to the *last* commit, and from there, Git can work backwards.

#### Your work-tree

Nothing in any existing commit can ever be changed!  Once made, every commit is frozen for all time.  That includes all of the files stored inside that commit.  Because commits are frozen—read-only—they work really well for archival.  But the files inside the commit are stored in a special, frozen, compressed, read-only, and Git-only format, that only Git can read.  These files literally cannot be changed, in the same way that no Git commit can ever be changed.  That makes these files entirely useless for getting any *new* work done.

The solution to this problem is to have Git *extract* the frozen committed files, from a commit, to a work area, where the files are turned back into ordinary files that your computer *can* use.  That's what `git checkout`–or in Git 2.23 and later, `git switch`—does: you tell it which branch you want to use, Git uses the branch *name* to find the correct *hash ID*, and Git extracts all the frozen files from that commit into your *work-tree* or *working tree*, which is where you can see them and work with them.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>This glosses over a lot of details about `git checkout`, so it's just an overview, not a precise definition.

---

#### The index

So, as you can see from this picture so far, there are really *two* sets of files that are active when you're working with a commit: the committed copies, which are frozen for all time (and not really visible at all), and the working copies, which you can see and work on.  Some version control systems stop here, with just two copies of each file.  Git, however, does not.

Git has something it calls, variously, the *index*, or the *staging area*, or sometimes (rarely these days) the *cache*.  The reason it has two (or three) names is probably a combination of things: the index itself is complicated, but the way you use it most of the time is relatively simple.  The term *staging area* refers to the way you use it.  I like to call it the index because of the fact that it takes on an expanded role during merges, and you'll eventually need to know about this.

In any case, a good way to think about the index is to pretend that it holds a *third* copy of each file.<sup>2</sup>  This extra index copy is in the *frozen format*, but isn't actually frozen: you can overwrite it with a new copy.  The copy of each file that is in the index is the copy that `git commit` will use when it makes a new commit.  This means you can view the index as *the files that will go into the next commit*, or, even shorter, the index is *your proposed next commit*.

So, what `git checkout` or `git switch` does, in effect, is to copy the files from the commit you chose to *both* the index *and* your work-tree.  The index copy is now ready for a new commit, and the work-tree copy is an ordinary file, stored in a folder because your OS requires that.  *Git's* copies of the file, in commits and in the index, is not stored in a folder at all.  They're in a special, read-only, Git-only format.<sup>3</sup>

What `git add` does—and this is the reason you must keep using it after modifying a file in your work-tree—is to copy the *work-tree* copy of the file into the index.  That is, it takes your updated work-tree file, re-compresses it and converts it to Git's internal frozen format, and *replaces* the old index copy with the new copy.  If you `git add` a file that was not in the index at all, that adds a *new* file to the index, but if you `git add` a file that *was* in the index, that just replaces the frozen-format copy.

The index *cannot hold a folder name*.  The files that are in the index just have long names like `path/to/file.ext`.  So when Git builds a commit *from* the index, the only things in the new commit are files.<sup>4</sup>  That's what prevents you from storing a folder.

When Git goes to *extract* a commit, if a file in that commit is named `path/to/file.ext` and your work-tree does not have a `path` folder, or the `path` folder is missing a `to` folder, Git will *create* `path` and `path/to` as needed.  So the fact that Git didn't store `path` and `path/to` in the first place is not important, except in one way: it's not possible to store an empty folder (empty directory) in a Git commit.<sup>5</sup>

---

<sup>2</sup>Technically, what the index holds is not a copy of the file, but rather a copy of the file's *mode*, its *name*, and a *blob hash ID*.  Unless you get into the inner workings of the index with `git ls-files --stage` and `git update-index`, though, it suffices to think of the index as holding a copy.

<sup>3</sup>Technically, again, these are actually *blob objects*, which have hash IDs, just like commits.  The hash ID of a blob object depends on the file content, and files can be *shared* across multiple different commits if the content matches, because each commit really just stores the blob hash ID.  This is all hidden underneath another layer of indirection: commits store *tree* hash IDs, and tree objects store name-and-mode-and-hash ID.  But you don't need to know any of this to *use* Git.  You *do* need to know about commit hash IDs and the index.

<sup>4</sup>Technically, the index can store:

- an ordinary file (mode `100644` or `100755`), or
- a symbolic link (mode `120000`), or
- a *gitlink* (mode `160000`).

All three of these are associated with a hash ID: a blob hash for a file or symlink, or a submodule commit hash ID for a gitlink.

<sup>5</sup>There are some tricks, none of which are entirely satisfactory: see [How can I add an empty directory to a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/115983/1256452)  The only one of these that really works is [the empty submodule trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58543445/1256452).

---

#### Tracked and untracked files

When you extract a commit, you get three copies of each of its files.  One is the frozen copy, in the current or `HEAD` commit.  The second is the frozen-format but replaceable copy, in the index.  The third is the only copy you can actually *use* yourself, in your work-tree.  You can see and touch the work-tree copies, as they're actual files, in actual folders, on your computer, instead of internal Git entities stored in some special Git fashion.

Because your work-tree is *yours*, though, this means you can create and remove files and folders all without Git ever getting involved.  Git won't *use* any of these files until you copy them into Git's index.  With `git checkout` (or `git switch` and/or `git restore`), you can command Git to *overwrite* your work-tree files with copies that Git has, but it's the index copies that will go into the *next* commit.

So what happens if you make a work-tree file and *don't* add it to the index?  The answer is: Git calls that an *untracked file*.

An untracked file is, very simply, a file that is in your work-tree right now, but is not in Git's index right now.  The *right now* part of this is crucial, because you can not only copy new files into Git's index—with `git add`, of course—you can also tell Git to *remove* files from its index, with `git rm`.

Running:

```
git rm path/to/file
```

tells Git: *remove the copy of that file from both your index and my work-tree*.  Now that it's gone from both, it *won't* be in the *next* commit.  Running:

```
git rm --cached path/to/file
```

tells Git: *remove the copy of that file from your index, but don't touch the work-tree copy.*  Now that it's gone from the index, it *won't* be in the next commit.

So, if you want some file to *not* be in a commit, you must remove it from the index.  That's fine as far as it goes.  If you remove it from the index, or never had it in the index in the first place, *and* the file exists in your work-tree right now, that file is an *untracked file*.

Untracked files can be annoying, as we'll see, but may also be pretty important.

#### `git status`

When you run `git status`, Git runs *two* sets of comparisons.  The first comparison compares the `HEAD` commit to the index.  For every file that is *the same*, Git says nothing at all.  For files that are different—or are new or have been deleted—Git says that this file is *staged for commit*.  Note that you cannot change the content of the `HEAD` commit,<sup>6</sup> so any change here is, by definition, something you changed in the index.

Having run this first comparison, `HEAD`-vs-index, Git now runs a *second* comparison.  It compares all the files in the index to the files in your work-tree.  For every file that is *the same*, Git says nothing at all.  For files that are different, or have been deleted, Git says that this file is *not staged for commit*.

Notice that we didn't mention files that are new yet.  For every file that is in your work-tree, but not in your index ... well, those are exactly your *untracked files*.  What `git status` does about these is *complain*, by listing them as "untracked".

---

<sup>6</sup>While you cannot change the content of *any* commit, you can—with `git checkout`—select a *different* commit to be the `HEAD` commit.  Or, of course, you can run `git commit` and make a *new* commit, and now that new commit *is* the `HEAD` commit.

---

#### Making `git status` shut up

About half of the purpose of a `.gitignore` file is to make `git status` *stop complaining* about an untracked file.  Listing a file name, or pattern, in a `gitignore` file makes `git status` *not* complain that the file is untracked.

This doesn't take any files *out* of the index.  **If a file is already in Git's index, listing that file in `.gitignore` has no effect.**  The file *is* in the index, so that copy of that file *will be* in the next commit ... unless, of course, you remove it yourself, with `git rm`.

#### Avoiding automatically-adding files that you don't want committed

The rest of the purpose of a `.gitignore` file is to enable you to use en-masse `git add` operations, without *also* copying some files that are currently untracked into Git's index.  Listing, for instance, `*.o` or `*.pyc` means that you can now `git add .` or `git add *`.  Git will *skip over* the untracked-and-ignored files, while copying other updated or new work-tree files into Git's index.

#### Untracked-and-ignored is therefore useful in two ways

Since those files *don't* get copied into the index, they *won't* be in the next commit.  Running `git status` with these files both untracked *and* ignored, you won't see them mentioned at all: they're not in the index, so they are untracked, but `git status` won't complain.  Running `git add .` with these files both untracked and ignored, `git add` won't copy them into the index.

#### But you already have the files in some existing commits

In your case, there are some commits that have some files somewhere within `app/http/`.  When you run:

```
git checkout <commit-specifier-or-branch-name>
```

and the commit you choose by this action is a commit that contains a file such as `app/http/foo.html`, Git will:

- create `app/http/` if needed
- write `foo.html` into that folder
- copy the frozen copy of `app/http/foo.html` into its index

and you'll be ready to work on / with that file.  But now the file *is* in Git's index, so it is *tracked* and `git status` will tell you about it and any en-masse `git add` will copy the work-tree file into the index, so that the updated `foo.html` will be in the next commit.

Even if you *don't* copy `foo.html` into Git's index, so that the index copy remains the *old* copy, that *old* copy will be in the new commits you make.  Git makes commits from the index, and the index has the old copy.

The obvious cure is to *remove* the index copy entirely, then make a new commit.  Now that the index copy is absent, there's no `app/http/foo.html` in the new commit.  If `app/http/` is in `.gitignore`, Git won't, from this point on in new work, *add* `foo.html` either.

But if you do this for *all* `app/http/` files, then, in the future, cloning this repository and extracting this commit to a new, otherwise-empty work-tree, you *won't* get a folder named `app/http`, because there will be no files whose name starts with `app/http/` to make Git notice that it needs to create the `app` folder and then the `http` folder within the `app` folder.

Moreover, suppose you now have a state in which you have commit `a123456...` (some hash ID anyway) that *does* have `app/http/foo.html` in it, and commit `b6789ab...` that *doesn't* have `app/http/foo.html` in it.  If you:

```
git checkout a123456
```

Git will extract all the files from that commit, including `app/http/foo.html`, into your work-tree and into Git's index ... and then, if you:

```
git checkout b789abc
```

Git will extract the files from *that* commit, notice that `app/http/foo.html` needs to be *removed* because it was in the previous commit—and thus is in the index now—and *isn't* in the commit you're selecting now, and hence must be removed from the index.  So Git will remove `app/http/foo.html` from the index **and from your work-tree**.

Listing `app/http/` in the top-level `.gitignore`, or `*` in `app/http/.gitignore`, not only tells Git that it should not automatically *add* these files *to* the index, it also gives Git permission to *destroy* these files in the work-tree in some cases, including this particular one.  So the fact that you have these files in some existing commits makes things dangerous if you select to `.gitignore` them.  After you've made sure all *new* commits *don't* have, and do ignore, these files, be careful when checking out historic commits!